# Close Popover (as UITableViewController) in Storyboard Scenario

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, uitableview, popover

I've defined a popover segue in IB (Storyboard) to open a UITableViewController which is embedded within a UINavigationViewController. I need this to navigate in the popover. 
Additionally I added two top bar buttons (save, cancel). After either is clicked I want to dissmiss/close the popover.

I tried different things but nothing works.

- Calling *DismissViewController(true, null);* has no effects
- Calling RemoveFromParentViewController closes my application (or just crashed?)

I've read about DismissPopoverController but this is not available in my scenario because of using an embedded UITableViewController in UINavigationViewController to work with prototype tables.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution after some try and error... I hope others get some benefit with my solution ;)

**In my base view:**

```
    public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        if (segue.Identifier == "MySegueIdentifier")
        {
            var popoverSegue = segue as UIStoryboardPopoverSegue;
            _myTableViewController = segue.DestinationViewController.ChildViewControllers[0] as MyTableViewController;
            _myTableViewController.PopoverController = popoverSegue.PopoverController;
            _myTableViewController.CloseCallback = AddNewTrAndRefreshCallback;
        }

        base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);
    }
```

```
    private void AddNewTrAndRefreshCallback()
    {
        if (myTableViewController == null || _myTableViewController.Cancled)
            return;

        var selectedRecord = _myTableViewController.SelectedRecord;
                    // Do whatever you want...
    }
```

**In my popover (UITableViewController embedded in UINavigationViewController)**

```
    partial void buttonCancelClicked (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem sender)
    {
        Cancled = true;
        CloseCallback();
        PopoverController.Dismiss(true);
    }

    partial void buttonDoneClicked (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem sender)
    {
        Cancled = false;
        SelectedRecord = _tableViewSource.SelectedRecord;
        CloseCallback();
        PopoverController.Dismiss(true);
    }
```

Dont hesitate to ask if anything is uncertain.